# C# Word Interop - Spell Checking in a Certain Language

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

For a customer of mine I need to force the spell checking in a certain language.

I have explored the MSDN documentation and found that when calling the `CheckSpelling()` method in the active document, it will invoke the spelling check. This method has parameters for custom dictionaries.

My problem is that I can't find anything about those dictionaries or how to use them.

Also there is still the possibility that there is of course another way to do this.

Can anybody boost me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found my solution:

```
foreach (Range range in activeDocument.Words)
{
    range.LanguageID = WdLanguageID.wdFrenchLuxembourg;
}
```

*Edit after comment*

Since my activedocument is in a variable I seem to lose the static Range property. I found a work arround by doing the following. (lan is my variable where i keep my WdLanguageId)

```
object start = activeDocument.Content.Start;
object end = activeDocument.Content.End;

activeDocument.Range(ref start, ref end).LanguageID = lan;
```

thanks @Adrianno for all the help!

Comment: As posted in the comment this works but check performances if you enumerate all ranges. In a big document it _could_ be **very** slow!

Answer (score 2):

The Spell Checker uses the **language of the text** to select rules and dictionaries (look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa168387%28v=office.10%29.aspx) to check how it works).

You have to set the text language to what you need and then SC will use that language. Follow this link for more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.language.aspx

Comment: I tried to set the activeDocument.Content.LanguageId but the SC didn't pick it up...

Comment: Did you try with ActiveDocument.Range.LanguageID = wdEnglishUS

Comment: I don't want any feedback or something. I just want to set the language of the SC in a predefined language... My customer is French and there are many kinds of french. And often word detects the wrong one...

Answer (score 2):

I have been working with this lately and thought I would add a bit to the already given answers.

To get a list of spelling errors in the document for a certain language, doing the following would get you going:

```
// Set the proofing language
myDocument.Content.LanguageID = WdLanguageID.wdDanish;

// Get the spelling errors (returns a ProofreadingErrors collection)
var errors = myDocument.SpellingErrors;

// There is no "ProofreadingError" object -> errors are accessed as Ranges
foreach (Range proofreadingError in errors)
    Console.WriteLine(proofreadingError.Text);
```

As pointed out by Adriano, the key is to specify the language of the document content at first, and then you can access the spelling errors for the given language. I have tested this (Word Interop API version 15, Office 2013), and it works.

If you want to get suggestions for each of the misspelled words as well, I suggest you take a look at my previous answer to that issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14202099/700926

In that answer I provide sample code as well as links to relevant documentation for how that is done. In particular, the sample covers how to carry out spell checking of a given word in a certain language (of your choice) using Word Interop. The sample also covers how to access the suggestions returned by Word.

Finally, I have a couple of notes:

- In contrast to the current accepted answer (your own) - this approach is much faster since it do not have to iterate through each word. I have been working with Word Interop for reports (100+ pages) and trust me, you don't want to sit and wait for that iteration to finish.
- Information regarding the `SpellingErrors` property can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.spellingerrors%28v=office.14%29.aspx).
- Information regarding the non-existence of a `ProofreadingError` object can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.word.proofreadingerrors%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Never user foreach statements when accessing Office object. Most of the Office objects are COM object, and using foreach leads to memory leaks.

The following is a piece of working code

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ProofreadingErrors errorCollection = null;

    try
    {
        errorCollection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.SpellingErrors;

     // Indexes start at 1 in Office objects
        for (int i = 1; i <= errorCollection .Count; i++)
        {
            int start =  errorCollection[i].Start;
            int end = errorCollection[i].End;

        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

    }
    finally
    {
        // Release the COM objects here 
        // as finally shall be always called

        if (errorCollection != null)
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(errorCollection);
            errorCollection = null;
        }

    }
```