# Word interop spell checking (determining when a word is spelled correctly)

Tags: c#, winforms, interop, spell-checking

I'm using Word's spellchecker to post process OCR, largely thanks to [Spell Checking in C# Using Word Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718687/spell-checking-in-c-sharp-using-word-interop) I've got the whole thing working in principle.

My problem is distinguishing between words that are correctly spelled and random sequences of garbage characters for which word's spellchecker has no suggestion.

```
foreach(string s in textBox1.Text.Split(' '))
{
    if(s.Length > 0)
    {
        //Get suggestions for this 'word'
        var suggestions = app.GetSpellingSuggestions(s, custDict, MainDictionary: Word.WdLanguageID.wdEnglishUK);

        //There is no suggestion, displays correctly spelled words and random nonsense for which word has no suggestion.
        if(suggestions.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(s);
        }

        foreach (Word.SpellingSuggestion spellingSuggestion in suggestions)
        {
            //Display the best suggestion then break.
            if (suggestions.Count > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(spellingSuggestion.Name);
                break;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Is there some mechanism to determine the 'score' of a suggestion or to differentiate between strings that exist in the dictionary and strings that don't?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you've figured it out, you can answer your own question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with the same problem, you can use the SpellingErrorType enum to discover if the string exists in the dictionary or not.